# How to create a Sync version of an Async method?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to achieve something similar to the methods you get with the core fs module where you have an Async method by default and a Sync method if requested such as `fs.readDir()` and `fs.readDirSync()`;

I have a method called `fetchUrls` that fetches files from a list of urls and returns a promise. I want to add another method called `fetchUrlsSync` which calls fetchUrls and blocks the thread until the promise is resolved. how can that be done?

sample code:

```
fetchUrls(startDate, endDate) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=> {
        // some async work...
    })
}

fetchUrlsSync() {
 // call fetchUrls and block until resolved
}
```

those two functions are methods on a class.

Comment: Why would you want that?

Comment: Just as a convenient because many operations after it depend on the files being available and I’m also curious how it can be done.

Comment: I am not sure you can do that because if the IO or whatever operation in fetchUrls is async, all you can do is resolve the promise being returned using .then. Else best is to rewrite the fetchUrlsSync using sync IO or sync Operation

Comment: There are convenient ways to do things after the operation has completed. I would really advise to stay away from synchronous solutions: it is bad practice.

Comment: You can't and you shouldn't. This is what async/await is for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't possible directly in node.js. It also goes against the general model in node, which is to perform all IO asynchronously.

It is however possible to use a compiled Node.js extension to achieve this called [`http-sync`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-sync).